# How to make a HTML page view in dark mode on default?

Tags: html, themes, blogger

```
   <div>
      <div class='flex fdcr aic mt-5 mr-13'>
        <label class='modeSwitch'>
          <input Onclick='darkMode()' class='check flex' type='checkbox'/>
          <span class='toggleSwitch'/>
        </label>
        <div>
```

This is a part of my HTML code. When the page is loaded it should be in dark mode on default. Is there a way to fix this without using `onClick.

I have even tried replacing `onclick` to default but it wasn't working.
I am new to HTML and please help me with this.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? you want to set the default theme dark? in that case , you also have to share the javascript code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the styles you need for the dark mode and light mode.

```
<style>
  body {
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  .dark-mode {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
  }
  .light-mode {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
  }
</style>
```

And then you can create JS functions that call the styles when you click the button.

```
<script>
  function darkMode() {
    var element = document.body;
    var content = document.getElementById("DarkModetext");
    element.className = "dark-mode";
    content.innerText = "Dark Mode is ON";
  }
  function lightMode() {
    var element = document.body;
    var content = document.getElementById("DarkModetext");
    element.className = "light-mode";
    content.innerText = "Dark Mode is OFF";
  }
</script>
```

[Check this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-dark-mode-for-websites-using-html-css-javascript/)
It shows a clear way to how to enable dark mode when you click.

Comment: i just need it in default

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you bit explain it.

Comment: well i just wanted to be it in default darkmode until someone doesnt click it it doesnt change to light mode

something like that

Comment: I hope now it's okay. I edited my answer. What I did was as the default style for the body I gave background color as black and color as white. So when you run the code in default it shows in dark mode. And then you can change the themes by clicking the buttons as your wish.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, but try this:

```
<input onclick='lightMode()' class='check flex' type='checkbox' checked/>
```

You need to add `checked` attribute to the input tag. And you need to create a `LightMode()` function to change the dark mode to light.

But it's only a one-use solution.

Comment: ic hmmmmmmmmmmmm